# Azure Cosmos python query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are trying to ping an azure cosmos db in python, which used to work. We are now getting the following error:

```
[2023-04-21T15:22:15.671Z] gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 498:
[2023-04-21T15:22:15.672Z] ActivityId : **-**-**
[2023-04-21T15:22:15.673Z] ExceptionType : GraphMalformedException
[2023-04-21T15:22:15.675Z] ExceptionMessage :
[2023-04-21T15:22:15.676Z]      Gremlin Malformed Request: GraphSON v3 IO is not supported.
[2023-04-21T15:22:15.677Z]      GremlinRequestId : **-**-**
[2023-04-21T15:22:15.678Z]      Context : global
[2023-04-21T15:22:15.679Z]      GraphInterOpStatusCode : M
```

With the following code:

```
        client = Client(
            url = cosmos_db_url,
            traversal_source = 'g',
            message_serializer = GraphSONMessageSerializer(),
            username=cosmos_db_graph_path, 
            password=cosmos_primary_key)
```

Does anyone know what could cause this? I have tried nearly every version of **gremlinpython** and it is always the same error.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "ping" Cosmos DB. As for your code: are you attempting this against a Cosmos DB instance that's been set up with Gremlin API? It would probably help to see more details, such as the URL you're using (obfuscated, please) and the path being passed as `username`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to ensure that you use the schema of the GraphSON v2, since it is the [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support) supported in Azure Cosmos DB. Check the json you are using and ensure that follows the supported schema.

> GraphSONv3 serializer isn't currently supported. Use GraphSONv2

Comment: We had to specify that we use ```GraphSONSerializersV2d0```